# Setting noopener for dynamic url

Tags: javascript, html, security, browser, window-object

I am trying to follow the advice from https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/noopener and https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/ and am trying to set the value for `rel` to be `noreferrer noopener`. The thing is that I cannot set the `href` value as it is dynamic. I need to make a Api call to my internal endpoint to get the url. As such I wonder whether the following will still work

```
   <a ng-click="getUrl()" rel="noreferrer noopener">
                            <i class="action icon view"></i>
   </a>

   var getUrl = function() {
         // call some endpoint, on success
         $window.open(url, '_blank');
   }
```

Is there still any value on setting `rel` value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn’t work: The `noopener` attribute won’t have the expected effect in the case in the question—that is, for a window/tab that’s opened from a link without the `href` attribute. Simple test:

```html
<!doctype html>
<title>simple noopener test</title>

<a onclick = "getUrl()"
rel = "noreferrer noopener">Case 1: click here to open a new tab that <b>will</b>
have access to the window object of this document (despite the'noopener')</a>

<p>
<a href="http://example.com"
rel = "noreferrer noopener">Case 2: click here to open a new tab that <b>will not</b>
have access to the window object of this document (because of the'noopener'</a>

<script>
var getUrl = function() {
  window.open("http://example.com", '_blank');
}
</script>
```

In Case 1 in that example, if you check the `window.opener` of the new tab/window that gets opened, you’ll see it’s non-null. But check the new window/tab in Case 2, and you’ll see it’s null.

> Is there still any value on setting `rel` value ?

No—for the case in the question, it seems there’s no value in setting `noopener`, because it’s not going to prevent the new window/tab from access to the `window` of the document that opened it.

Comment: Thanks. What about using the `window` object returned in `window.open` and then doing `window.opener = null`?

Comment: Yeah for the workaround, see https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/#recommendations: You’d need to do it this way:`var otherWindow = window.open();
otherWindow.opener = null;
otherWindow.location = url;`.